# Running "partially trusted" .NET assemblies from a network share

Tags: .net, security

When I try to run a .NET assembly (`boo.exe`) from a network share (mapped to a drive), it fails since it's only partially trusted:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Assembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
   at BooCommandLine..ctor()
   at Program..ctor()
   at ProgramModule.Main(String[] argv)
The action that failed was:
LinkDemand
The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
boo, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=32c39770e9a21a67
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
Intranet
The Url of the assembly that failed was:
file:///H:/boo-svn/bin/boo.exe
```

With instructions from [a blog post](http://www.georgewesolowski.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,4cc5fcdf-cc68-4cf0-a083-b22a8bdc92d6.aspx), I added a policy to the .NET Configuration fully trusting all assemblies with `file:///H:/*` as their URL. I verified this by entering the URL `file:///H:/boo-svn/bin/boo.exe` into the *Evaluate Assembly* tool in the .NET Configuration and noting that boo.exe had the *Unrestricted* permission (which it didn't have before the policy).

Even with the permission, `boo.exe` does not run. I still get the same error message.

What can I do to debug this problem? Is there another way to run "partially trusted" assemblies from network shares without having to change something for every assembly I want to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With .NET 3.5 SP1, .NET assemblies running from UNC shares have full permissions.

See Brad Abrams's [Allow .exes to be run off a network shares](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2007/10/26/adhoc-poll-allowing-net-exes-to-run-off-a-network-share.aspx) for workaround and discussions, and finally the follow up [.NET 3.5 SP1 allows managed code to be launched from a network share](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx).

Comment: Interesting. It's possible Windows 7 locked down executables run over network shares, managed or native.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem by using [`caspol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28VS.80%29.aspx) as instructed in Johnny Hughes' blog post [Running a .Net application from a network share](http://johnnynine.com/blog/RunningANetApplicationFromANetworkShare.aspx):

```
caspol -addgroup 1.2 -url file:///H:/* FullTrust
```

It seems the .NET Configuration GUI for managing the policies simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the 'caspol.exe' program (provided with .NET runtimes).  You will have to do this on the machine you are trying to run the application from.  I wasn't able to 'mark' and assembly (probably just me).  However, using caspol and setting up the proper permission for my app, LocalIntranet_Zone, fix my similar issue.

I have heard (but haven't tried it yet), that .NET 3.5 sp1 removed this tighten security requirement (not allowing .NET assemblies to reside on a share by default).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add the [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx) attribute to your assembly.  The error message implies that something that's calling into your boo.exe assembly is not fully trusted, and boo.exe doesn't have this attribute allowing it.