# Loading Assemblies from the Network

Tags: security, .net-3.5, dll, assemblies, networking

This is related to the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468/running-partially-trusted-net-assemblies-from-a-network-share) and the answer maybe the same but
I'll ask anyways.

I understand that we can start managed executables from the network from .NET
3.5 SP1 but what about assemblies loaded from inside the executable?
Does the same thing apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been able to load Assemblies from the network at leasst from .NET 2.0. I have used this on a previous project. The only thing to watch is the size of the assembly and the number and size of the dependancies that it is loading.

If you are using a seperate AppDomain, then you will need to take special consideration of the dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is yes, you're trying to load an untrusted module into your local app domain.