# Running asp.net application from UNC path

Tags: iis, windows-server

I got a problem with IIS. I am trying to host application from UNC path, but I get errors - that it can't load assemblies from bin folder.
Is there something tricky I am missing or it just can't be done? I am providing all the credentials needed in Physical Path Credentials, I also tried running the application pool as the allowed user, but it seems the problem is different..

PS: I am running .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Running an IIS app from a UNC is generally not a good idea for both security and reliability reasons, however the [Running “partially trusted” .NET assemblies from a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468/running-partially-trusted-net-assemblies-from-a-network-share) question here on stackoverflow will probably help you.

Comment: Well, lets say in my scenario I can't copy it to local storage and I must run it from that shared folder. I tried caspol, but it seems I don't do it right or it just doesn't work. The problem seems that it can access the share, but it doesn't have permission to load the assemblies from bin.

Comment: @llianlliev What version of Windows are you running on your web server?

Comment: osFamily=2(Windows Server 2008 R2)